# Cofibre sequence $S^n \rightarrow S^n \rightarrow M(\mathbb{Z}/p,n)$. When does $f$ induce multiplication by $p$ on homotopy groups?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Problem: Let $p$ be an odd prime, let $n>2$, and let $M(\mathbb{Z}/p,n)$ be the cofibre of the degree $p$ map $f:S^n \rightarrow S^n$. In what range of dimensions (depending on $n$) does $f$ induce multiplication by $p$ on homotopy groups?

My first question is how is $M(\mathbb{Z}/p,n)$ the cofibre? I thought the cofibre of $A \hookrightarrow X$ was $X/A$ always. Is $M(\mathbb{Z}/p,n)=S^n/pS^n$ ? Why or why not?

Wouldn't a map of degree $p$ induce multiplication by $p$ on all homotopy groups? Based on how the question is worded, I'm sure I don't have the right idea here. Does this have something to do with the stable homotopy groups of spheres?

Comment: You can get that it is a moore space by the LES of homology groups. Why do you write that the degree p map an inclusion of CW complexes? This is not true.

Comment: @AndresMejia I thought cofibrations were always to be thought of as inclusions, but I see what you're saying that the degree p map isn't an inclusion. Can you please provide me a bit more detail on finding the cofibre using LES in homology?

Comment: they can for good spaces, but I think you might be mistaking cofibration with cofiber. see [here](http://www.home.uni-osnabrueck.de/mfrankland/Math527/Math527_0306.pdf). I also don't have time but I gave a quick google and the problem is worked out [here](http://uregina.ca/~franklam/Math527/Math527_HW10_sol.pdf). If you're still stuck later I can do my best to write out an explanation.

Comment: The 'cofibre' here means 'homotopy cofiber'. i.e. the mapping cone of $f$. If $j:A\hookrightarrow X$ is a cofibration, then $X/A$ is homotopy equivalent to $C_j$ under $X$. To see that you need some hypothesis on dimensions take $n=2$ and consider the Hopf map $\eta:S^3\rightarrow S^2$. You have $f\circ\eta=p^2\cdot \eta$. My hint is to use the Freudenthal Theorem.

Comment: It's not obvious, but precomposition and postcomposition by a degree n map are not always the same. I believe they agree in the case that the map you are composing with is a co-H-space map. In particular, the suspension of any map is a co-H-space map, so the most obvious class of maps you might hope to understand for this question are the maps in the image of the suspension homomorphism. Now I'm sure this is not known in general, but like Tyrone says, the Fruendenthal Theorem gives a range in which all are.

Comment: In fact, it is instructive to try to write a proof of why precomposition and postcomposition would agree, and see why it fails.